# Custom ProjectSchemaDefinitions in Project Property Sheet

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I finally managed to configure my Visual Studo C++ Project to show my Custom ProjectSchemaDefinition if I take a look at a Single Project->Property.

[image: Concrete Property Sheet]

My Question:

**Is there any way to show this in a Shared Project Property (eg external.props) ?**

My current shared.targets configuration

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Import Settings">
    <UseDefaultProjectTools>true</UseDefaultProjectTools>
    <UseDefaultPropertyPageSchemas>true</UseDefaultPropertyPageSchemas>
    <UseDefaultGeneralPropertyPageSchema>true</UseDefaultGeneralPropertyPageSchema>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(SolutionDir)\props\PublishConfig.xml">
        <Context>Project</Context>
    </PropertyPageSchema>
    <ProjectTools Include="PublishConfig" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I think I miss just the right *Context* in this definition but cannot find any reliable source at msdn where different Context Targets are correctly described.

Thank you in advance